# update js value on data get from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

In the process of creating a price, I need to get data from the server about selected options which affect the final price.

So I created a class `Price` with a method of calculation:

````js
class Price {
    constructor () {
       this.totalUnitPrice = 0
    };

    _updateTotal () {

        // apply lang rate
        this.totalUnitPrice = 0;
        this.totalUnitPrice += +this.basePrice.value + +this.langRate.textContent * +this.basePrice.value / 100;

        // apply price unit lot
        this.totalUnitPrice = this.totalUnitPrice * this._getQuantityLength();

        // apply options
        for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length ; i++) {
            if (this.options[i].selected) {
                this._get_option_value(this.options[i].value);
            }
        }

        // apply period
        this.totalUnitPrice += this.period * this.totalUnitPrice / 100;

        let total = this.totalUnitPrice * +this.quantity.value;

        // display
        this.dTotalUnit.textContent = this.totalUnitPrice.toFixed(2) + ' €';
        this.dTotal.textContent = total.toFixed(2) + ' €';
    }

     // At this time, ```this.totalUnitPrice``` is not updated

    _get_option_value (opk) {
        var that = this;
        aGet({"option": opk}).then(
            function (data) {
                if (data.is_percent === true) {
                    that.totalUnitPrice += that.totalUnitPrice * parseInt(data.price) / 100
                } else {
                    that.totalUnitPrice += data.price
                }
                console.log(data.price);
                return data;
            },
        );
    }


}
````

and a small function to make get requests:

```js
async function aGet(args) {
    return await $.get("", args);
}
```

The problem here is that the price is calculated correctly except for the options that are not updating the price outside their own scope. I thought using await/async would solve my problem. I was wrong. How is it possible to achieve my goal then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get out of the promise's scope you need to use the async/await syntax for your `_get_option_value` function

```
async _get_option_value (opk) {
    try {
        const data = await aGet({"option": opk})
        if (data.is_percent === true) {
            this.totalUnitPrice += this.totalUnitPrice * parseInt(data.price) / 100
        } else {
            this.totalUnitPrice += data.price
        }
        console.log(data.price);
        return data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```